# Can't mass-assign error with nested forms in ActiveAdmin edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am putting together an ActiveAdmin project with many different relationships. On in particular is an products table with a categories table. When a user clicks on a product to edit it I would like to also be able to edited its associated category if need be. However I get the following error when I do.

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: items_category_attributes

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"n9zPI/IASZP/UhaE5NA/I0v4bB1qfpcxhaEi64ZH2qY=",
 "items_design"=>{"name"=>"EDITED",
 "description"=>"dsfdsf",
 "style"=>"",
 "brand"=>"",
 "color"=>"",
 "items_category_attributes"=>{"name"=>"test 2",
 "parent_id"=>"1",
 "id"=>"2"}},
 "commit"=>"Update Items design",
 "id"=>"1846"}
```

items_design.rb

```
attr_accessible  :description,
                   :image_name,
                   :item_id,
                   :name,
                   :category,
                   :items_category_id

                   belongs_to :items_category, foreign_key: :items_category_id 
                   accepts_nested_attributes_for :items_category
```

item_category.rb

```
attr_accessible :name,
                  :parent_id

  has_many :items_designs
  has_many :subcategories, :class_name => "ItemsCategory", :foreign_key => "parent_id", :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "ItemsCategory"
```

app/admin/item_designs.rb

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs "Details" do
      f.input :name
      f.input :description
      f.input :style
      f.input :brand
      f.input :color
    end
    f.inputs do
      f.has_many :items_category, :allow_destroy => true, :new_record => false do |cf|
        cf.inputs :name
        cf.inputs :parent
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does items_category_attributes come from?
If you change it to just items_category I think that should fix it.

Comment: I believe that is either and an artifact of the nested form or ActiveAdmin or both. If I add items_category_attributes to attr_accessible the error is gone but the form doesn't submit at all.

Comment: Does item_design belongs_to or has_many items_categories? Your model and form are different.

Answer (score 0):

`ItemsDesign` belongs to `ItemsCategory` but your form is putting `ItemsCategory` as nested attributes of an `ItemsDesign`

You can only save attributes on associated records through the parent. [Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)